# Find embedded object in array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, api, mongoose

I am using Mongoose and Express to create an API and need your help to find a specific document inside the `hotels` array. I need to find the document with an `id` matching a specific value.

Here is the schema:

```
{
  "_id": "5e181fed9fc1883a69797e3a",
  "hotels": [
    {
      "name": "Hotel Emperador",
      "stars": 4,
      "price": 1596,
      "imagen": "https://i.ibb.co/RHYqxjL/hotel1.jpg",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Hotel Sonesta",
      "starts": 4,
      "price": 2400,
      "imagen": "https://i.ibb.co/kx06vbZ/hotel2.jpg",
      "id": "sonesta"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hotel Soratama",
      "stars": 3,
      "price": 1000,
      "imagen": "https://i.ibb.co/hx0Txk6/hotel3.jpg",
      "id": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need something like this response, for the `get_id` in my api, but I cannot do it, can you help me?

```
{
  "name" : "Hotel Emperador",
  "stars" : 4,
  "price" : 1596,
  "imagen" : "https://i.ibb.co/RHYqxjL/hotel1.jpg",
  "id": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework to retrieve the document

```
hotelModel.aggregate([{
    $match:{
        _id: "5e181fed9fc1883a69797e3a"
    }
},{ $project: {
          hotels: { $filter: {
              input: '$hotels',
              as: 'hotel',
              cond: { $eq: ['$$hotel.id', 1]}
          }},
          _id: 0
      }

},{
   $unwind:"$hotels" 
}])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/ka5WAdCvuZG

references:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/